# Is there a name in Hebrew that means "God is my portion"

Tags: names

Is there a name in Hebrew that means "God is my portion"? When I google translate I get אלוהים הוא החלק שלי which I have no idea how to say.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilkiah

Comment: ........ה' חלקי

Comment: Nach(a)li'el? 15

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer to me...

Comment: I'm not sure the question is on topic

Answer (score 2):

What you Googled would be the very long form of saying it as a sentence in modern Hebrew:

> Elohim hu hachelek sheli

(The "ch" there is not "as in cheese", but rather some [voiceless fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative) that is difficult for many monolingual native English speakers to pronounce. Often they'd substitute either an "h" or a "k.")

Please oh please don't attempt to name anyone that.

Many Hebrew names use contractions, for example:

- Taking out the "is" ["hu"]
- For "my portion", long form is "ha-chelek sheli" [*the portion that is mine*] or cut it down to simply *chelki* (I think that's called declension?)
- And for "God", you can use shorter forms such as "el" or "yah."

So as DoubleAA commented above, there is [a Biblical character named Hilkiah.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilkiah) From "Helki", *my portion*, "yah", *God*.

Another suggestion in the comments above was *Nachaliel*; again following the same rules. The "el" is a short form for God. *Nachalah* means like an inheritance or estate; *nachali* makes it "mine", then tack on an "el." (It's used as a place name in [Numbers 21:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.21.19?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en).)

Comment: This is a very in depth answer that not only goes into great and accurate detail of the grammar of words and their meaning, but also highlights a more accurate pronunciation of Hebrew letters for the simple sake of accuracy. +1 from me